# DECLARE is not valid in this position, expecting EOF.... MySql error

Tags: sql, mysql, database-cursor

I tried to create a cursor in MySql using the following code. but I get the `DECLARE is not valid ...` error. why?

```
DECLARE CastCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT * FROM Customers
where cust_email IS NULL;
```

Comment: DECLARE can be used in compound code block only and must be placed at the same beginning of it, before any other statement.

Comment: 'MySQL supports cursors inside stored programs.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: NB cursors should be a last resort where you have to iterate row by row and as such can be slow..